# PHP function not accepting variable

Tags: php, function

i have a simple function to display some html.

function is included in the corefunctions.php file.

I call the function and pass a word to it, but nothing gets passed. Shows up as blank. What am i doing wrong?

```
function showCities($pagetype) {
echo "pagetypeis: ".$pagetype;

//more code

}
```

I call the function from another file like this

```
$pagetype = "places";
showCities($pagetype);
```

All i see on the screen is 'pagetypeis:'

Thanks

Comment: is it possible the rest of the code somehow affecting the result? because that part seems to be fine.

Comment: i just removed all other code in the function and still the same problem..

Comment: what do you seel if you var_dump($pagetype) inside the function ?

Comment: try renaming all $pagetype variables with anything else.

Comment: looks like I was calling the function in another part of the code but without passing the variable.  I changed that and it works now.  THANKS GUYS!

Answer (score 1):

This works just fine: (see it on [tehplayground](http://tehplayground.com/#4ecec55822cd7))

```
function showCities($pagetype) {
    echo "pagetypeis: ".$pagetype;
}

$pagetype = "places";

showCities($pagetype); #=> pagetypeis: places
```

In your function, try var_dump

```
function showCities($pagetype) {
    var_dump($pagetype);
}
```

What do you see?

Comment: Its strange because i have other functions in the corefunctions.php file and they work fine.  Although all others i just pass numbers to.

Comment: @vpets then you have made a typo in a variable name you use as parameter in  your function call, or the variable is reset between its assignment and its use as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me here: http://codepad.org/vBALy4Yj

This is why it's good to use an IDE. If it were a misspelling, usually the IDE would warn you about it before even running the code. I recommend [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt) or [Zend Studio for Eclipse](http://www.zend.com/products/studio/).

I guess the next thing I would check for is *multiple definitions of `function showCities()`*.

Answer (score 1):

Try set error level to see notices.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

May be you've mispelled variable name, e.g. "a" in $pagetype is cyrillic "a", not latin?

Comment: hmmm.. error shows Warning: Missing argument 1 for showCities(). checking the line number.

Comment: but its just referring to this line function showCities($pagetype) {

Answer (score 0):

Must be the other code, works fine for me, check it out [here](http://ideone.com/uCu0z).